# ElasticSearch call to DocumentExists triggers an exception (C#)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have the following call:

```
var Exists = Driver.DocumentExists<Mydata>(Id).Exists;
```

It checks if a document exists with the Id passed as a parameter.
The call behaves as expected, however it throws some exceptions that get caught, but appear in the debugger on every call where a document is not found:

```
Exception: Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
("The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.").
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
("The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.")
```

This is making the code run insanely slow in the debugger. Am I missing something, or is it the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

[The default `IConnection` implementation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.x/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Connection/HttpConnection.cs#L39) (the type that makes the actual HTTP request) in NEST for desktop CLR uses [`HttpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) internally which throws a [`WebException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception(v=vs.110).aspx) when a 404 HTTP status code is returned.

Since the default behaviour of the client is not to throw on exceptions, and some endpoints quite rightly can return a 404 (which NEST knows about), the exception is caught internally but could still show up in the debugger.

Comment: I understand the logic behind; the problem is that it makes code that has to delete a lot of documents that may / may not exist unbearably slow. In our case we do have to sometimes delete tens of thousands of documents and it is so slow that it renders elastic search totally unusable, which is sad because the search is excellent.

Comment: Deleting tens of thousands of documents is ,relatively, the worst performing operation in Elasticsearch due to the way in which Lucene works under the covers. If you can, it is a good practice to partition documents into separate indices, and delete the entire index but depending on the use case, this is not always possible. You can issue the delete document without checking that the document exists; the response indicates if the document was found or not.